# Conditional .Net Health Check, based on earlier test results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, health-check

Is it possible to have run-time conditions to health checks, or a way to stop/bail certain health checks?

I have a .Net applications that is relying on two external web services: A) an IdP where I get an access token; and B) a "custom service" where I use this access token.

```
  _builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddCheck<DatabaseHealthCheck>("Database-access")
            .AddCheck<CertificateHealthCheck>("Find-certificate")
            .AddCheck<TokenHealthCheck>("Request-token")
            .AddCheck<DownloadHealthCheck>("CustomService");
```

To use the custom service, I need an access token, and to get the access token, I need a valid certificate on the machine. So I made three different health checks for these.

However, if I test without a valid certificate, I get the error message tripple.

- `CertificateHealthCheck` fails, since it could not find a certificate
- `TokenHealthCheck` fails, since it could not find a certificate to sign the token request
- `DownloadHealthCheck`, since getting an access token fails because no valid certificate could be found

Is there a way to only test `TokenHealthCheck` and `DownloadHealthCheck` if the previous tests are healthy?

Comment: Incorporate all 4 tests in a single IHealthCheck class and implement it according to your wished behavior?